# How to make "assign places to people" editor as usable as possible

Tags: web-applications, editor, usability, entity-relationship

So we have **places** and we have **people**. the added complexity is **additional metadata** attached to each link between each pair. Like date range when a person spent at a particular place.

I know. Lots of data and many possibilities.

One way of doing this is by having a list of people and when you click on one, a modal dialog opens, where a list of places is displayed. When you select a place, you also have to enter a date range.

From a usability perspective and quick relation editor this is almost definitely not the optimal solution. User focus changes several times and that slows things down + makes users tired since they have to be very concentrated and focused = higher rate of human error.

I would like to avoid dialogs. Do you maybe know of a website where a similar thing is done = *two entities need to be related with additional metadata*.

The main **requirements** of this page are:

- simplicity
- avoid modal dialogs **if** possible

What I'm trying to do: **many-to-many editor with additional metadata data on each pair**.

### Questions

1. What would you suggest? Provide any ideas (even dumn ones).
2. Do you know of a public site (so it can be checked) that has this kind of scenario implemented?

Answer (score 0):

doesn't this come down to two operations select and connect. you'd select some group of people or places via a number of different paths string search, time, space, or such and then you'd connect them by creating some record

note that useful relations aren't just between one person and another or one place and a person or just one place and another although when storing these they can all be reduced to a->b tuples but this can be ignored if the relations you have only have one person place and time

this sort of reminds me of [Entity Workspace](http://www.google.com/search?q=Entity+Workspace) but in that case they were dealing with data collection in the domain of crime investigation so they had names addresses phone numbers dates and such as base types which in their setup were drag and drop on to cards

so if you took that you could have a center file and a list of people after some filtering to add that one to this set you'd drag it from the list and like wise from the places you'd have another list to drag from

commonly referenced ones might be shown in another place and this would work a bit like putting the toppings on a pizza and when your done you put it in the oven or commit it if you want to later undo this it would keep the set together so you can remove it later if you didn't want it or you can add something

and this wouldn't have any of the dialogs you suggest and as such it could be called mode-less

Comment: You're right about having a modless process. But if I understand your example it's just a relation between two entities without any additional relation metadata. Let's think of a single person and places. You have to relate a person with each place while also providing for instance the day when that particular person was at that particular place. Now think of X people, Y places and think of an editor that handles this... Dragging/adding whole groups isn't an option any more, since you have to attach additional data to each relation/link between a person and a place.

Comment: yes but once you've collected the set relating the elements is another matter and in fact some times just a set of things expresses a relation between them that can't be said